# Detect functions with too long length (>100 lines)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coding-style, jshint

Is there any way to detect the functions in my Node App that are longer than 100 lines?
Im using JSHint but it doesnt have any option to detect it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do such a thing with jslint, according to the docs :

> Warning This option has been deprecated and will be removed in the
>   next major release of JSHint. JSHint is limiting its scope to issues
>   of code correctness. If you would like to enforce rules relating to
>   code style, check out the JSCS project. This option lets you set the
>   maximum length of a line.

the poperty `maxlen` is deprecated you don't have to rely on it

Comment: "maxlen" lets you set the maximum length of a line. Im trying to detect number of lines of a function.

Comment: Same, jslint does not provide a rule for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use eslint and use the `max-statements` option to allow a maximum number of lines in a function
Link : https://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-statements

Comment: "max-statements" lets you detect a max umber of statements in a function. Im trying to detect number of lines of a function.